# Adjust Principled BSDF Emission Falloff Rate?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, emission

Using Blender 3.0, I'm trying to adjust a material's emission falloff rate and strength.

I have a Principled BSDF shader that is emitting light, however, I'm struggling with the Emission Strength. The distance is fine, but I want the start of the falloff to be brighter.

Hopefully you can see my setup (copied from Rich Sedman) in the image below. I have added a plane in order to better see the falloff rate.

[image: Emission strength from a distance]

From a distance the emission source does not appear very bright, but when zoomed in very close, it becomes plenty bright with a strange gradient effect. Something to do with the Light Path node I suppose?

[image: Emission strength close up]

Can you think of a way to adjust the brightness of the source WITHOUT changing the falloff distance? Perhaps there is a far simpler way to achieve this.

Comment: Which Enterprise D is it, the one by Chris Kuhn? I'm not sure if this setup is really needed, and depending on what you want to achieve exactly you may test the following setups: get rid of everything except for the _Light Falloff_ node plugged into a _Math_ node and then into _Emission Strength_. Now just try to set the _Math_ node to **1.** _Square Root_ or **2.** to _Power_ with an _Exponent_ value slightly below 1 like 0.9 or 0.8 for example.

Comment: Haha, it's mostly my own. There were several folks' versions I incorporated. That was years ago though. Thanks for the suggestion. This definitely helps the brightness, but I'd like the falloff rate to be faster. Any ideas how to achieve that?